# How to change google map's custom address info bubble on iPhone?

Tags: google-maps, infowindow

I'm trying to customize google maps info window(or address bubble).
Question: How to change person's image and address info(if it's possible)? 
I want to put my icon instead of person's image, and "SMART" (or any company name) instead of "130 River St". (It seems this bubble appears only on iPhone, I didn't see on Android.)
I'm showing map by this url: http://www.google.com/maps?q=boston

Thanks
 
[image: google map's custom address info bubble]

Answer (score 0):

Its pretty hard to suggest something without actually some code snippet, but assuming that you are the one who has written the info window code then its pretty simple, like so

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
content: contentString
});
```

where the contentString is the part that you want to display in HTML format, like

```
var contentString = '<div id="content">Hello</div>';
```

You can always add image and any other image. As long as its displayable in an HTML page it can be shown in the infoWindow.

About the infoWindow viewable only in the iPhone browser, I guess its written that way, either by browser detection or the latest feature detection functionality of JQuery.

Hope this helps.